# plupload: validate image dimensions before upload?

Tags: jquery, validation, plupload

i checked the Docs but couldn't find anything .. is there a way to validate image dimensions of a file before uploading? I want to add a rule for minimum image dimensions and display an error message in case the image is too small.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i could find it out by myself:

Put this inside the `FilesAdded` function:

```
plupload.each(files, function(file, i)
{
    var img = new mOxie.Image;
    img.onload = function () {
        var wi = this.width;
        var he = this.height;
        // you can validate here
    };
    img.load(file.getSource());
});
```